# Xcode 3 ctime declaration issues

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am in the process of porting my c++ engine to mac, and so I used premake to generate an xcode project, which it does fine.

Box2D is built into the engine and one of its files "b2Broadphase.h" is including algorithm from the c++ standard library.

This is giving these errors: `::clock_t has not been declared` and so on for all the `using` commands in the ctime file.

I cannot figure this out because when using premake to build a make file it runs fine and build a perfect library on OSX. Its only Xcode giving these errors.

Comment: Is the error at runtime, link-time, or while you are editing?

Comment: When the program i being compiled so link-time I suppose

Comment: is the file you're including the .h file in a ".m" file or a ".mm" file?

Comment: Its .cpp, Does that make a difference from .mm?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Xcode has not been configured to include the *implementation* files (.m or .cpp) or it has not been configured to link against a library which you are using. In general, you need to do two things: 1. include the headers 2. link against the libraries with the actual executable objects.

In Xcode, you do this by selecting the project (top-most item) in the file-browser panel on the left, and there is a section in the main area to choose which libraries to link to. You must specifically tell it to link against whichever libs you are using, even if you have imported their headers.

For .cpp or .m implementation files, you need to tell it to include that file in the target for compilation. This can be done either in the build settings (similar place to the lib inclusion) or else when you have a file selected, the inspector panel on the right has a little area for you to choose which targets to include the file in. (you only need to "include" implementation files like this, not .h files)